# lightbox2 in app with zoom in phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, lightbox2

I am working on a phonegap app. I have few set of images where I am trying to use the [Lighbox2](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) plugin.

I have included the required js and css files. How do I add the related property in my  html, so that It works in the apk which I build using the phonegap.

I also wish to have the zoom feature on the phone on finger pinch, is that possible with lightbox 2?

```
<a href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/33/b8/69/33b869f90619e81763dbf1fccc896d8d.jpg">
 <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/33/b8/69/33b869f90619e81763dbf1fccc896d8d.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
</a>

<a href="http://webcareinfoway.com/images/Web_pics/android-logo-transparent.png">
 <img src="http://webcareinfoway.com/images/Web_pics/android-logo-transparent.png" alt="Smiley face">
</a>

<a href="http://webcareinfoway.com/images/Web_pics/android-logo-transparent.png">
 <img src="http://webcareinfoway.com/images/Web_pics/android-logo-transparent.png" alt="Smiley face">
</a>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tj0b63vo/) where I want to use the Lightbox2.